# Strange behaviour on highcharts with two Y Axis

Tags: highcharts

Im doing a chart with 2 series. One of the series is 'scatter' type and the other is 'column' type.
The problem i have, is that when i only have the scatter series, datetime labels on x axis, starts on the extreme left, but when i add the column series, is like all labels are pushed to the center, and i dont know why.

This is my fiddle examen: https://jsfiddle.net/cswpgq8u/7/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
},
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: 1633057200000,
            max: 1634353200000,
            tickPositioner: function () {
                var ticklist = [];
                var extremes = this.getExtremes();
                var startDate = extremes.min;//this.min;
                var endDate = extremes.max; // this.max;
                var diff = moment.duration(endDate - startDate);
                if (diff.days() * 1 > 10)
                    increment = moment.duration(2, 'days').asMilliseconds();
                else
                    increment = Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / 10);

                for (var timeline = startDate; moment(timeline) <= moment(endDate); timeline += increment) {
                    ticklist.push(timeline);
                }
                return ticklist;
            },
            maxPadding: 0,
            minPadding: 0,
            crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                events: {
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 1634266800000,
                color: 'green',
                width: 1,
                dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
                label: {
                    text:  "AHORA", // Content of the label. 
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    rotate: -90,
                    textAlign: 'right',
                    x: -2,
                    y: 30,
                    style: { color: '#6d6d6d', fontSize: '8px', fontWeight: 'bold', backgroundColor: 'white' }

                },
            }],
            plotBands: null,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    var xMin = this.axis.min;
                    var xMax = this.axis.max;
                    var labeltick = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d. %B', this.value);
                    if ((moment(xMax).diff(moment(xMin), 'days')) < 10) {
                        labeltick = Highcharts.dateFormat('%d. %B %H:%M:%S', this.value);
                    }
                    return labeltick;
                },
                x: -10 
            }
        },

yAxis:[
    {
            plotLines: [{
                id: 'ln-' + 'idEje1',
                color: '#9FA0A2',
                width: 0,
                value: 0,
                dashStyle: 'longdashdot'
            }],
            labels: {
                enabled:true,
                x: -5,
                y: -3,
            },
            title: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            lineColor: 'lightgray',
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickInterval: 1
        }, {
            title: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            lineColor: 'lightgray',
            opposite: true,
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
                x: -15,
                y: -3,
            },
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickInterval: 1
        }
],

plotOptions: {
},

series: [
                    {
                    yAxis: 0,
            type: 'scatter',
            minPointLength: 1,
            allowPointSelect: false,
            stack: true,
            data: [{
                x: 1634007600000,
              y: 2,
              value: 2,
              marker: {
                  symbol: 'circle',
                  radius: 3,
                  fillColor: 'red',
              },
              type: "ttf"
            },
            {
                x: 1633748400000,
              y: 5,
              value: 2,
              marker: {
                  symbol: 'circle',
                  radius: 3,
                  fillColor: 'red',
              },
              type: "ttf"
            },
            {
                x: 1633143600000,
              y: 2,
              value: 2,
              marker: {
                  symbol: 'circle',
                  radius: 3,
                  fillColor: 'red',
              },
              type: "ttf"
            },
            {
                x: 1633402800000,
              y: 2,
              value: 2,
              marker: {
                  symbol: 'circle',
                  radius: 3,
                  fillColor: 'red',
              },
              type: "ttf"
            }],
            name: 'On YAxis 0',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormatter: function () {
                    var point = this;
                    return "Valor TTF:" + ' <b>' + point.y + ' Días</b><br/>';
                },
            }
                    },
          {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            allowPointSelect: false,
            minPointLength: 1,
            data: [{
                      x: 1633708800000,
                      y: 5,
                      type: "duracion",
                      value: 5
                  },
                  {
                      x: 1633881600000,
                      y: 3,
                      type: "duracion",
                      value: 3
                  }],
            name: 'On YAxis1',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormatter: function () {
                    var point = this;
                    return "Duración:" + ' <b>' + point.y + ' minutos</b><br/>';
                },
            },
            pointWidth: 1
          }
]
```

});

**With 2 series**

[image]

**With one series**

[image]

I think this is happening because Column Series. But dont know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional space is caused by the default calculation of `pointRange` for column series. You need to define it by yourself:

```
    series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            ...
        },
        {
            type: 'column',
            pointRange: 1,
            ...
        }
    ]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hsrxtjaw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange

Comment: That's it. Thanks!